# Android How to Sync Two Async tasks?

Tags: java, android

I need to combine two lists each of which is returned after its own separate Async Call. How does one best coordinate Async calls like these.  Are there any standard SDK methods for waiting until another async task has completed?

Comment: What about combining the work of both asynctasks in a single one?

Comment: Or using AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(singleThreadPoolExecutor) handle queuing execution.

Answer (score 6):

`execute()` call returns an instance of `AsyncTask`, you may save this instance to check later, if the task has finished or not by calling `getStatus()`, so your code will look like this:

```
final AsyncTask<...> first_task;
final AsyncTask<...> second_task;

public someMethod() {
    first_task = new MyFirstAsyncTask().execute();
    second_task = new MySecondAsyncTask().execute();
    // other things
}

private class MyFirstTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
    // business as usual

    protected void onPostExecute(SomeData[] result) {
        if( second_task != null && second_task.get_status() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED ) {
            // start the task to combine results
            ....
            //
            first_task = second_task = null;
        }
    }
}

private class MySecondTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
    // business as usual

    protected void onPostExecute(SomeData[] result) {
        if( first_task != null && first_task.get_status() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED ) {
            // start the task to combine results
            ....
            //
            first_task = second_task = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the task, which finishes last, can start the new task to combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on the need.

Do you need to wait all of the data to arrive? If not just make a call yo your function with synchronized block function in your activity

If yes, do you expect them to work only once; therefore two(or X) at total? maybe you can check: CoundDownLacth (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java has some nice stuff such as Future class and the likes. No use to describe this framework here there are many resources on the net. It may be better though to have a single async task anyway there is really no need to run two async tasks at the same time. You can do both parts in a single doInBackground